# Mobile version of website

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, resolution

How i can make my website to look good on mobiles?

i dont mean here Responsive web design. I just want to show my website as a mini version of website where user can zoom. A lot of website works this way.

I have to change all % values into px values in CSS?

If then, what value should that be?

One default value for destops and mobiles?

My website: http://www.badzlepszy.pl/luckypixels/

Answer (score 1):

Just the same website, only zoomed out on your mobile device? Remove the viewport.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`